# server and delivery url for receiving http post request

Tags: java, http-post

My system needs to interact with a third party system to receive some alert information.

I need to setup a delivery url and build a receiver web app that will listen to http POST requests from the third party system which will contain this alert information in JSON format.

My system is based on Java. As per my understanding, i need to setup up a url 
like http://www.myexample.com:1111 which will be be a Java server program listening at a particular port number. But the example the third party has provided for the delivery url is of the format http://www.myexample.com:1111/testapp.

Can experts in this field guide me on how to go about developing the server for this particular need and how to decide on the delivery url which i need to provide to the third party?

i already have a Java Struts2 web application running on Apache Tomcat at the url http://www.myexample.com:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [THIS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)
simple guide. You need only one REST method (GET), so you should add some more details to @RequestMapping annotation in GreetingController class, like:

@RequestMapping (value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
And that could work.

Comment: Thanks maxie.i have never worked on REST or created a web service, other than consuming web service through client stubs. Do you mean to say i need to develop a web service to receive the http post request? and can that be done in Struts2?

Comment: Unfortunaly, I havent worked much as REST-Client, but to receive and handle request - yep, we need a service ) Unfortunately again, I dont know how to do it with Struts.. sorry )